# How to add a custom block within checkout cart summary in magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-block, checkout-summary

How to add a custom block within checkout cart summary in magento 2

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create this file in your custom module/theme to add custom Block on cart page.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.totals.container">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout.cart.custom.block" before="checkout.cart.totals" template="Vendor_Module::custom-block.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

You need to create one template file here in your module or your theme.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/custom-block.phtml

Content for this file..

```
<?php echo "Custom Block"; ?>
```

**Output :**

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if this solution works for you.

Comment: ya its working. thank you

Comment: You're always most welcome Buddy! :)

Comment: hi, I have used the above code but the issue is that it gets added multiple times. By multiple times I meant is that when the second product is added to cart then it displays twice.. Any idea why this is happening..

Comment: @KishanSavaliya, how to add this after the sub total?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create layout file checkout_cart_index.xml at below path and paste this below code :

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="cart.summary">
        <block name="summary.custom.block" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  template="VendorName_ModuleName::temp.phtml" after="checkout.cart.shipping" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Add this phtml file :

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/temp.phtml

```
<?php echo __("Hello"); ?>
```

Cache clean and refresh the page.

Comment: how to move this after subtotal?

Answer (score 0):

Just override checkout_cart_index.xml file and add your custom block using after or move keyword

Comment: welcome to Magento SE. Please explain a bit more while answering, so that people can understand it better.

Comment: Sure Sir , Thanks