# Magento2- How to add a block after Cart Total on Cart and Payment

Tags: magento2, cart

In Magento 2.3.5 How can I add a block of code/static content after Cart Total on `checkout_cart_index.xml` and `checkout_index_index.xml`?

I want this block should be observable so that if Cart Total changes it should also reload.

Want to add content below Order Total likewise on the payment review section also

[image]

Cart Total is changing according to product fees radio buttons (Mageworx Multi Fees extension)

Comment: please share screenshot

Comment: @Himanshu I have updated question.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294487/how-to-add-a-custom-block-within-checkout-cart-summary-in-magento-2

Comment: You can use after instead of before in checkout_cart_index.xml

Answer (score 2):

try:-

create custom phtml exmaple:- custom.phtml

> path:- app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/custom.phtml

add code in checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="cart.summary">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom" template="Vendor_Module::custom.phtml" before="checkout.cart.methods.bottom"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

create custom html

> path:- app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/custom.html

create custom js

> path:- app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/custom.js

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Vendor_Module/summary/custom'
            }
        });
    }
);
```

add code checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="itemsBefore" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="custom" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/custom</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: it is working on the cart page, how to show on the payment summary page.

Comment: please check the updated answer.

Comment: how to show after subtotal?